# replace redirect after registration with json output

Tags: php, json, authentication, laravel, laravel-5

in laravel 5 I use the default registration method to create users for an api. The default behaviour after a successful registration is a redirect to "/home".

```html
curl --data @formdata -k https://foo.bar.com/auth/register
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=https://foo.bar.com/home"
 />

        <title>Redirecting to https://foo.bar.com/home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="https://foo.bar.com/home">https://foo.bar.com/home</a>.
    </body>
</html>
```

Instead of the redirect I want to return JSON information, e.g.

```
{ "Message" : "Success" }
```

Currently I do not know where I have to configure that. I tried to return that in the Register method. But that did not change the behaviour.

#### app/Services/Registrar.php

```php
class Registrar implements RegistrarContract {

    // ...

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    public function create(array $data)
    {

        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            // ... 
        ]);

        return ["Message" => "Success];
    }
}
```

Furthermore I found a lot of information to change the redirection path, but not how to change the return output.

**How can I return json information after a successfull registration, instead of the redirection?**

Comment: you can accept my answer for further readers if it was helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

Just override `postRegister()` method in `AuthController`:

```php
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->registrar->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return view('auth/register')->withErrors($validator->errors());
    }

    Auth::login($this->create($request->all()));

    return response()->json(["Message" => "Success"]);
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you name it `postSignup()`? Then I have to integrate it somehow in the default registration process. Which I do not know how? When I change it to `postRegister()` to overwrite it, it will run into the if-condition with `view('auth/signup')` which does not exsits.

Comment: copy-paste typos, sorry :) Amended my answer, take a look.

Comment: In your code the creation of the user was missing. I added `$this->registrar->create( \Input::all(  ) );` a line above the return statement and the user will be created. Unfortunatly, I get now Error-messages in HTML (not JSON) when things go wrong. E.g. if I post two time the same request....

Comment: @jerik you're correct, my mistake :) Please see updated answer.